# Movie about a man murdering his wife and almost getting away with it

Tags: identify-this-movie, mystery

About 10 years ago I watched this murder mystery movie. It followed a cop investigating an attempted murder, and his prime suspect was the husband.

The husband was toying with the police, knowing they would not find evidence that would lead to a conviction. I think the police did get the case go to trial, but the husband was acquitted. Because he would not get sued again for the same thing, he opened up to the cop.

What he didn't count on was that the wife, who was still in the hospital died in the meantime, so using the confession, the cop brought the case to court once again, this time for murder.

One last detail I remember about this movie was that the husband had some sort of marble track.

**Release Year:**

I think around early 2000s.

**Country of Origin:**

This movie was definitely from the US.

Comment: *"Marble Track"* ?

Comment: @Paulie_D [marble track (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMsH-LaC7Bk)

Comment: It sounds like something from a Columbo though I guess that's not what you're looking for. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Possibly [Fracture](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488120/) with [Anthony Hopkins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000164/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) and [Ryan Gosling](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0331516/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) from 2007. It matches your description perfectly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_(2007_film)).

Hopkins plays the husband (Ted Crawford) who tries to kill his wife. He then defends himself in court against the character played by Gosling (Willy Beachum). He wins the case and is set free. He then let's is wife die in hospital. But Beachum finds the gun (Crawford had exchanged it for a cop's weapon during the fight after he had shot her) and the gun still contains ammunition with his finger prints on them - now, it's murder and he can prove it.

And Ted Crawford builds devices like [marble tracks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488120/mediaviewer/rm3681649664), he even gifts one to Beachum.

Trailer:

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66940/discussion-on-answer-by-anne-daunted-movie-about-a-man-murdering-his-wife-and-al).